# Magento2.3.3 - Loading first product image if no base, small or thumbnail image is set?

Tags: magento2, product-images

How can I get the first product image of a product, If none of the products images are set as base, small or thumbnail image?

In all the examples I found based on getting base, small or thumbnail images for a product.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
){
    $this->product = $product;
}

public function getImageByProductId($id){
    $product = $this->product->load((int)$id);
    $small_img = $product->getData('small_image');
    $thumbnail = $product->getData('thumbnail');
    $image = $product->getData('image');


    if ((empty($small_img) || $small_img == "no_selection") ||
        (empty($thumbnail) || $thumbnail == "no_selection") ||
        (empty($image) || $image == "no_selection")) {

        $firstImageObject = '';
        $images = $product->getMediaGalleryImages('images');
        if (!empty($images)) {
            $img = 0;
            foreach ($images as $imagkey => $imgvalue) {
                if ($img === 0) {
                    $firstImageObject = $imgvalue;
                    $img++;
                }
            }
            print_r($firstImageObject->getData());
        } else {
            echo 'no images found';
        }
    }
}
```

try this one.

Comment: Which file do I need to edit with this code?

Comment: this is standalone function. Its up to case by case, where you would like to use.